# Button click event not firing when inside form tags

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I have a contact form on a website that sends the form to the website owner via e-mail.

Clicking the button **btnSubmit** runs the vb code behind to send the e-mail, which was working fine until I styled the form using Bootstrap and then the button click event stops firing.

If i take the button outside the parent form tags it works again, but i want it to be inside so it will trigger the HTML5 validation on the required fields.

**The code not working:**

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtName">Name:</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" type="text" CssClass="form-control" required />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtEmail">Email address:</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" type="email" CssClass="form-control" required />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ddlProduct">Product</label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProduct" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataSourceID="SQSItemNames" DataTextField="itemName" DataValueField="itemName">
            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtMessage">Message</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" runat="server" type="text" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5" required />
    </div>

    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Send" CssClass="btn btn-primary pull-right" />

</form>
```

**Edit:** Not sure if this makes a difference but the page in question references a master page.

Comment: How many form tags have you got on the master page in total?

Comment: There are two form tags on the master page

Comment: You should only ever have one - so an open and a close - if you have a form inside a form that will knock out your functionality - to still use bootstrap I usually replace the form tags with div tags

Comment: Thanks for that, I changed the bootstrap form in the master page to a div and it started working straight away. If you post this as an answer I will mark it as confirmed so you get the rep!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only ever have one set of form tags - so an open and a close.

If you have a form inside a form that will knock out your functionality.

If you still want to use bootstrap styling you can replace the form tags with div tags.

Answer (score 2):

your code is not calling your event in the code behind, lacking reference the event in his button, for example:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Send" CssClass="btn btn-primary pull-right" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't resolve the problem, the issue was in fact having multiple forms, one being inside the master page. Once I removed the master page form it worked, As a check I also added the click event but this resulted in sending the e-mail twice!

Answer (score 0):

I use Razor, not web forms, so this might be a little off in the syntax, but try using

```
<asp:input type="submit" ... />
```

That way you are explicitly telling the button that it is to submit the form.